# How do I use a value from the superquery inside a subquery?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to create a query that shows the last name of an employee, the employee id, the last name of the manager of that employee and the id of that manager.

The last name, id, and the manager id of that employee is easy to do because it is already in one row, which means that the following is sufficient:

```
SELECT last_name, employee_id, manager_id FROM employees WHERE manager_id IS NOT NULL;
```

But to get the last_name of the manager, you have to search the same table by the manager id you got from the employee. The solution I found is:

```
SELECT last_name, 
       employee_id, 
       (SELECT last_name FROM employees WHERE employee_id = manager_id), 
       manager_id 
FROM employees 
WHERE manager_id IS NOT NULL;
```

However, it seems that 'manager_id' doesn't work in the subquery (although I expected that) and the output is NULL (for the manager id, all the other columns do have values).

So my question is, how can I use the manager_id in the subquery?

Side note: The manager_id can be different for each employee, so using a constant value doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a correlated subquery.  I strongly, strongly recommend that you use table aliases and qualified column names in *all* your queries.  However, these are particularly important with correlated subqueries.

You should write this query as:

```
SELECT e.last_name, e.employee_id,
       (SELECT m.last_name
        FROM employees m
        WHERE m.employee_id = e.manager_id
       ),
       e.manager_id
FROM employees e
WHERE e.manager_id IS NOT NULL;
```

The alias `e` is an abbreviation for the table reference to `employees` in the outer query.  The alias `m` is an abbreviation for the table reference in the subquery.

Notice that *all* column references use the table alias.  This makes the query unambiguous, can prevent unexpected errors, and makes the query much easier for you and others to understand.

Comment: +1 for taking the time to explain, in clear terms, what you are doing here and why. The willingness to help a less experienced fellow is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a self inner  join  ( a join with the same table)

```
SELECT 
      a.last_name
    , a.employee_id
    , b.last_name 
    , a.manager_id 
FROM employees  a 
INNER JOIN employees  b ON b.employee_id = a.manager_id;
```

The inner join  work only if a.manager_id is not null so you  can avoid this where condition

Comment: I was able to get it working by changing the query to: `SELECT 
a.last_name, a.employee_id, 
(SELECT b.last_name FROM employees WHERE b.employee_id = a.manager_id),     
a.manager_id 
FROM employees a INNER JOIN employees b ON b.employee_id = a.manager_id
WHERE a.manager_id IS NOT NULL;` but the query from Gordon Linoff worked without modifications, so I'll accept his answer.

Comment: `, b.last_name FROM employees WHERE employee_id = manager_id` is completely wrong

Answer (score 1):

When you want to refer to a table in the outer query, you need to either use the full table name like `table.field` or, as in your case, if the outer query table is same as the subquery table, you need to assign an alias to the outer query table and use it in the subquery like this:

```
SELECT 
last_name, employee_id, 
(SELECT last_name FROM employees WHERE employee_id = emp_outer.manager_id),     
manager_id 
FROM employees emp_outer 
WHERE manager_id IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: This is mostly correct, and the "minimal" solution (although Gordon's advice to use a table alias for the subquery copy of the table is indeed very good advice, even if not strictly required). Alias for the outer query is required, and is what you show here. However, two points: In Oracle, you can't use the keyword "AS" before a table alias (that will throw a syntax error); you can only (OPTIONALLY!) use the word "AS" before a column alias. And, it is generally best to use (very) short aliases for tables. "emp_outer" is technically correct, but it will be a lot of typing if you use it a lot.

Comment: @mathguy I provided a minimal solution and a long alias so that it is clear to the OP how to refer to an outer table. Good point on the 'as' keyword, I didn't know oracle doesn't allow it, since I don't use Oracle much.. thanks